# How to ETL from BigQuery to BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, etl

I have an external data source that will load data into several tables, in batch mode, several times a day. However, the tables need cleanings, transferring, joining, etc...
Once raw tables are transformed they are visualized on data visualization software (PowerBI or Data Studio).
Now the question is how to update the result tables every time new data is loaded into raw tables?.
In BigQuery creating a table from other tables then when updating the source tables they don't update the created tables, right?
Another solution is to use something like cloud composer to query source tables and load data into destination tables.

[image]

Comment: You have a few ways, one way is Cloud Workflow, it does all your steps, also there is Eventarc if you want to automate with a custom script in Cloud Run.

Comment: @Pentium10 what about cloud compiser (Airflow) ?

Comment: If you have expert in that field, it's good as well. Other solutions are more or less un-maintainable as they work out flawlessly. No library to maintain, no updates, just glue other and they work. Depends on the customizations you want to do as well.

Comment: The best thing to do  depends a lot on your particular use case but Cloud Composer (or Apache Airflow on a Compute Instance) with dbt might be a good option.

Comment: I had the similar requirement where I was using big query schedule queries to load data from RAW to Base tables and creating pub sub message to trigger the schedule queries using cloud functions(with certain limitations). However, we are now using Google Workflows to organize and sequence all the actions. Look for this article here https://medium.com/codeshake/build-a-serverless-bigquery-ingestion-pipeline-using-cloud-workflows-f893f6b701ee. Let me know if you need more information on this.

Comment: @radhikasharma I am using Cloud Composer here but still have some issues and gaps in my architecture